# want my form's values to show in another div after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ticket form and when they click buy, I would like it to be saved and shown in another div as "user's ticket information" plus they are also able to buy a new ticket and add to the old one after. It doesn't have to be saved in a database or anything, for example when you click refresh all info would go away and you can start from fresh. Another example of how I do it is when I sign up, the user information will go to my memory class. Any javascript/jquery/html will help. Bellow is a start of what im working at. Thanks ^^
[image: ticket example]

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="buyTicket" action="" method="POST">
                   <div id="ticketHeader">Buy Your ticket here</div><br></br>
                   <div>Number of persons :<input type="number" required id="numberOP" value="" placeholder="number of persons"/></div>
                   <div>Flight Destination:<input type="text" required id="destination" value="" placeholder="hawaii/thailand/spain"/></div>
                   <div>Depature          :<input type="text" required id="depature" class="datepicker" value="" placeholder="enter depature date"/></div>
                   <div>Return            :<input type="text" required id="return" class="datepicker" value="" placeholder="enter return date"/></div>
                   <div><button type="submit" class="button" id="buttonTicket">Buy Ticket</button></div>
             </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the div on the same page? I can't see the Ticket Information DIV in your code

Comment: yes it's right next to it (u can see it from the example image):) I didnt put it cos it's just an empty div. here's the code: <div id="ticketinfoheader">Ticket Information: </div><div id="ticketinfo"></div>

Comment: Will clicking submit not change the location anyway or are you planning to use AJAX to send the ticket information to the server?

Comment: it's a little project so only javascript/jquery/html :) it doesnt need to be there all the time, but it should save untill i click refresh and be able to add tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like ben said use `.val()` http://api.jquery.com/val/ to get the values.  Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/YNez9/

You will have the div, which shows the selected values floating to the right

```
<div id="result" style="float:right;">
</div>
```

and on submit you want to add the values entered\ or have a placeholder that you can set its value then make it visible

```
$('#buyTicket').submit(function() {
  $('#result').append('<div>Number of persons :'+$('#numberOP').val()+'</div>');
  //.....
  //return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the val() function to get the values from the form once the button is clicked. Api documentation available here: http://api.jquery.com/val/. Perhaps in something a bit like this:

```
$('#buttonTicket').click(function() {
    $('#ticketinfoheader').text($('#numberOfPersons').val());
});
```

Comment: It showed the info for 30 millisecond LOL. I kinda want it longger than that. any ideas?

Comment: It's because the form is being submitted I suspect. Have a look at D3mon's answer. By returning false he is preventing the submit action being completed. Have a read of this: http://api.jquery.com/submit/.